# Jquery plugin script order

Tags: html, jquery, plugins, cdn

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap and My Cart -->
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
 ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"
 src="../Jquery-cart-add/cart.js"
 ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="../Jquery-cart-add/jquery.mycart.js"
 ></script>
 
<!-- Modal Vanilla Js -->
  <script src="../product landing page/modal.js"></script>
  <!-- Owl Sliders -->
  <script src="../product landing page/owl carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../product landing page/owl carousel/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="../product landing page/owl carousel/jquery-min.js"></script>
 
<!-- Product Gallery -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../product landing page/product_gallery/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../product landing page/product_gallery/zoom.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../product landing page/product_gallery/script.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Number Spinner -->
 <script src="../product landing page/number spinner/jquery.nice-number.js">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../product landing page/number spinner/jquery-number.js">
 </script>
</body>
```

Can someone tell me please what's the problem here?My add to cart jquery plugin works fine by itself on another page but when i try to add it in my project it doesn't work.I tried to switch my jquery min and bootstrap cdn under all the scripts and it works but then the zoom gallery plugin and number spinner don't work.Please tell me what am i missing.Thank you.

This is the error in the browser.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).myCart is not a function
> jQuery 9
>
> i
> fireWith
> ready
> J
> promise
>
>
>
> cart.js:16:23
> jQuery 9
>
> i
> fireWith
> ready
> J
> (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
> promise

here are all the plugins

https://github.com/cristi-20/Plugins-.git

Comment: without your script js , it will be difficult to help you

Comment: Do you need the script that gives the error in the console?

Comment: yes i'll see after

Comment: why you have to refer multiple versions of Jquery?

Comment: the first one is not there.it's a mistake.

Comment: can anybody help me please!